# How to apply a condition on each item of a Matrix in MATLAB and get the same size of the input matrix and calculate the number of ones?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to set the values that are less than 0.0038 to one (1), and the rest of the values will be zeros (0), then I need to calculate the number of ones in the following matrix (berMap_mean) that has the size 41*41.

[image]

What I have done is:
First, I applied a condition that must show me a matrix with the same size that has 0 and 1 with the below condition

```
isSmaller = berMap_mean(berMap_mean < 0.0038);
```

isSmaller must be a matrix that has only zeros and ones of the same size of the above matrix due to the above condition as shown below.
[image]

Then I wanted to calculate the number of ones in the above-sketched matrix with the following condition.

```
numSmaller = sum(sum(isSmaller(:) == 1));
```

Then apply the following equation
`Coverage_area = (numSmaller/(41*41))*400`

***But I couldn't get the matrix that I wanted in the first condition but I got something different as shown below, and the second two following conditions are showing me nothing.***

[image]

Any assistance, please? You can consider the berMap_mean any random map with the size of 41*41 double.

%% Calculate the coverage area

```
isSmaller = berMap_mean(berMap_mean < 0.0038);
numSmaller = sum(sum(isSmaller(:) == 1)); 
Coverage_area = (numSmaller/(41*41))*400
```

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem is. What does `isSmaller` look like?

Comment: @BillBokeey isSmaller must be a matrix that has only zeros and ones of the same size of the above matrix due to the above condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression for `isSmaller` looks right, that will give you a `logical` array the same size as `berMap_mean`. You can simplify the next expressions by using `nnz` to count the number of non-zero elements, and `numel` to count the number of elements.

```
fractionSmaller = nnz(isSmaller) / numel(isSmaller)
```